# Histogram with bins a percentage of values?

Tags: python, algorithm, histogram

I am creating a histogram in python and I want the bin edges to be a percentage of given values (5-10%).  What would be the best way to go about this so that I don't leave gaps in the bin boundaries, and don't have to pre-set some values for the bin boundary calculation?

Comment: What are you using to plot it?  pyplot has a `hist()` function which does this for you which may be of use.

Comment: I am using pyplot, but I need to give it bin boundaries using the bins=myBins keyword.  Pyplot default is equally sized bins.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it's convenient to create histograms using pre-defined tools like [numpy.histogram](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.histogram.html) , though your newly posted comment- suggesting that you're using matplotlib- is also totally fine. Either way allows you to create a set number of automatically determined bins of equal width...

```
import numpy
data = [0,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,3]
hist, edges = numpy.histogram( data , bins = 10)
>>> hist
array([1, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 2])
>>> edges
array([ 0. ,  0.3,  0.6,  0.9,  1.2,  1.5,  1.8,  2.1,  2.4,  2.7,  3. ])
```

...Or, in the odd case where you want predefined bins (possibly of different width), you can specify the bin edges yourself (read the docs for information on how this works):

```
>>> hist, edges = numpy.histogram( data , bins = [0,.5,1., 1.5,2,3])
>>> hist 
array([1, 0, 6, 0, 3])
>>> edges
array([ 0. ,  0.5,  1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  3. ])
>>>
```

Just **be careful about using drastically different bin sizes**, however.  In many cases this sort of coarse graining could distort the relationships between the numbers you're trying to compare.

As for your value +/-10% boundary?

```
preferred_bin_centers = [0,1,2,3]
bin_pairs = [ ( 0.9* v , 1.1*v ) for v in preferred_bin_centers ]
>>> [[0.0, 0.0], [0.9, 1.1], [1.8, 2.2], [2.7, 3.3000000000000003]]
```

Or, flattened into a list form that could be used by numpy.histogram...

```
bin_edges = sum( [  [ 0.9* v , 1.1*v ]  for v in values ]    , [] )

>>> [0.0, 0.0, 0.9, 1.1, 1.8, 2.2, 2.7, 3.3000000000000003]
```

(Note from the first two items of the above list that this code gives confusing bin edges if one of your bin centers is 0; I left that in solely as an example of what to watch out for)

Incidentally, the bin edges as defined above will also create intermediate bins outside your desired range. For example, if you bin items within +/- 10% of 1,2, and 3, then inherently, there will also be a bin between 2.2 and 2.7 (the "outside edges" of your desired bins) where numbers like 2.5 would go. If you have values that exist in between your desired bins, then you may want to adjust your cutoffs or visualization accordingly.

Comment: This is closer to what I was looking for - how would you go about creating the boundaries so there are no gaps? (in your example there is a gap between 2.2 and 2.7, for example).

Comment: @Jen... the inherent problem here is that the boundary values in this method are manually chosen. This means that you need to be very careful in choosing your bin edges, especially since the +/10% criterion results in larger bin sizes for larger bin centers (the bin around 1 has a range of 0.2, while the bin around 3 has a range of 0.6). Is there a particular reason why equally spaced bins aren't appropriate for your data set? Remember, it's ok for some of the bins to be empty.

Comment: Yes - equally spaced bins are not appropriate due to changing resolution conditions.

Comment: Without knowing more about the dataset, it's hard to recommend a good way to choose bin edges that doesn't distort the data. (such as by making some bins three times larger in an area with equally spaced data) You may want to start by going through the data and picking out the different regions of the dataset where resolution settings are different.... then define equally sized bins for each subset. Or you may want to histogram the sets separately to start, and use that to choose your settings. Looking at your data is a good first step, and thankfully it's easy to experiment!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm oversimplifying your question?

```
def bins(data, nbins):
    range = max(data) - min(data)
    binsize = range / float(nbins)
    bins = [x * binsize for x in range(nbins)]
```

Comment: Can you do these sorts of overloads?  When I run this it returns equally sized bins, which is not what I want.  The kludge I made is to create a list and then append to that list using the percentage I want: [mybins.append(mybins[i]*percentage) for i in range(nbins)]

Comment: So you want each bin to contain 10% of the values?  In that case just sort the array and take every `(num_elements * 100) / percentage`th element.

Comment: no - not 10% of the values - the bin boundaries are value +/- 10 %. (ie, 4.5 - 5.5 (bin center 5), or 90 - 110 (bin center 100)).